# Can I use USB tethering to update during installation?

Tags: 18.04

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 but I don't have internet access through router. I use USB tethering instead.

While installing Ubuntu if I tick an option stating "download updates while installing" and I connect USB cable as net cable (USB tethering) will it work or it will require some drivers to install?

Comment: "How to use Usb tethering in Ubuntu" is not what you asked in the body. I altered the title. hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

> and I connect USB cable as net cable(USB tethering) will it work

Generally: yes. USB tethering depends on the ability of the phone to connect to the internet.

USB tethering you can test it with the live session: set it up, open a browser and an internet page. When you see the page it will also be available for updates.

> or it will require some drivers to install.

No. The part that is used for this is USB and USB uses generic drivers.

> While installing Ubuntu if I tick an option stating "download updates while installing"

Mind that it as a slow and a probably untested method. If the connection drops so does your install. As there is no reason to download updates while installing why would you want to tick it? You can also do it afterwards when the system is installed or at any moment you do have a cable or wireless connection to the internet.